# Kendo UI for JSP - Coulmn data in GRID as anchor link to other window

Tags: jsp, user-interface, for-loop, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How can i show data for one of the column as link(href) in the grid. i tried to use template , but gives cannot compile jsp error.

```
<kendo:grid name="grid" selectable="multiple">
        <kendo:grid-pageable pageSizes="true" buttonCount="5" />
        <kendo:grid-sortable mode="multiple" allowUnsort="true" />
        <kendo:grid-columns>
            <kendo:grid-column title="num" field="rowNum" width="130px" />
            <kendo:grid-column title="Test Id" field="testId" width="130px" template="<a href='#test.html'>#: testId#</a>"/>          
        </kendo:grid-columns>
        <kendo:dataSource data="${List}" pageSize="15">
            <kendo:dataSource-schema>
                <kendo:dataSource-schema-model>
                    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="rowNum" type="string" />
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="testId" type="string" />                                           
                    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
                </kendo:dataSource-schema-model>
            </kendo:dataSource-schema>
        </kendo:dataSource>
    </kendo:grid>
```

here i want testId to be displayed as link and when i click on the link i want to open a  new window for showing more details.

Comment: What is the error? I far as I know, using number sign (#) in template may break template.